# Two Condition Where-clause SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause

I need to filter some rows when 2 conditions are met, but not excluding the other rows.

Table:

```
idRow   idMaster    idList
1         10        45
2         10        46
3         10        47
4         11        10
5         11        98
6         14        56
7         16        28
8         20        55
```

Example:

When:

- idMaster=10 and id List=45 (only show this combination for idMaster 10)
- idMaster=11 and idList=98 (only show this combination for idMaster 11)
- list all other rows as well.

Expected result:

```
idRow   idMaster    idList
1         10        45
5         11        98
6         14        56
7         16        28
8         20        55
```

Running SQL Server 2014

I tried combinations of CASE IF but all cases only filter the idMaster=10,11 and idList=45,98, excluding the other rows

Comment: Please show the queries you tried and explain how and why they don't match your expectation

Comment: Pretty sure you have logical ANDs and ORs combined incorrectly, but we need to see your work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you didn't mentioned the database name, this following query logic will be applicable for all databases-

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE idMaster NOT IN (10,11)
OR (idMaster = 10 AND idList = 45)
OR (idMaster = 11 AND idList = 98)
```

Comment: Just so there are not bad feelings.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed do this with a (nested) `case`. Hopefully this helps you understand better.

```
case idMaster
    when 10 then case idList when 45 then 1 end
    when 11 then case idList when 98 then 1 end
    else 1
end = 1
```

This might be the best though:

```
not (idList = 10 and idList <> 45 or idList = 11 and idList <> 98)
```

Overall it's usually beneficial to avoid repeating that list of values in multiple places. Both of these avoid the need to keep things in sync when changes come.